# Allow only a single editable field at once in a custom component

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working in webforms and have a series of entry fields with follow the same pattern. They have a label to show the text which can toggle to a text field with a click of a button thereby saving it.

I only want the user to have a single field being edited at once, such that if they begin editing a second field, the first field will save.

My code as is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace vk_HVK_Web.User_Controls
{
    [ValidationProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:EditableLabel runat=server></{0}:EditableLabel>")]
    public partial class EditableLabel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler OnSave;
        public static EditableLabel CurrentEditing;
        public string DisplayText { get
            {
                return this.Text.ToUpper();
            }
        }
        public string Text { get => txtInput.Text; set => txtInput.Text = value; }

        public bool Editable { get => txtInput.Visible; set => txtInput.Visible = value; }

        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Editable)
            {
                txtInput.Visible = true;
                lblText.Visible = false;
                btnEditSave.CssClass = "fas fa-save";
                sectionEditable.CssClass = "col";
            }
            else
            {
                lblText.Visible = true;
                txtInput.Visible = false;
                btnEditSave.CssClass = "fas fa-pencil-alt";
                sectionEditable.CssClass = "col col-form-label text-left";
            }
            lblText.Text = DisplayText;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = txtInput.Text;
        }

        protected void btnEditSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Editable)
            {
                Save();
            } else
            {
                Edit();
            }

        }

        public void Edit()
        {
            if (CurrentEditing != null && CurrentEditing != this && CurrentEditing.Editable)
                CurrentEditing.Save();
            CurrentEditing = this;
            Editable = true;
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            Editable = false;
            if (OnSave != null)
                OnSave(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't believe the code from design is useful but here it is anyways:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditableLabel.ascx.cs" Inherits="vk_HVK_Web.User_Controls.EditableLabel" %>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4 col-form-label text-right">Start Date: </div>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" id="sectionEditable">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox Visible="false" ID="txtInput" runat="server" Text="" OnTextChanged="txtInput_TextChanged" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <div class="col-4 col-form-label">
                                <span><asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnEditSave_Click" /></span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when they click the button to edit, the first thing it does is it checks if something else is being edited, and if it is, to save it. The save method, changes the state of the component and should make it no longer editable.

As in stand, the toggling alone works great, but calling the static variable's `Save()` method doesn't seem to affect it's state at all.

Help would greatly be appreciated. I'm very new to webforms, so if I'm doing state management wrong, please tell me how to do it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be done on the client-side?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk With JavaScript? Would be great, but this is part of an assignment where non-webform stuff is supposed to be kept to a minimum. So I'm looking for a server-side solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so this took me 2 days, but I know have a much understanding of ASP.NET.

My solution was 2-fold, the first was that, for some reason, I thought that static lifetimes are per user, like in front-end frameworks which isn't the case. This meant that it was shared across all users, and all pages. Not good, right?

Since I wanted to have it per-page, I used `ViewState`. User Controls have their own `ViewState`, and I needed the `Page`'s, but it was `protected` and I was prevented from using it.

I exposed `ViewState` using the following extension class:

```cs
    public static class SharedViewStateExtension
    {
        public static StateBag GetProtectedViewState(this Page page)
        {
            var viewStateField = typeof(Page).GetProperty("ViewState", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            return (StateBag) viewStateField.GetValue(page);
        }
    }
```

Of course, whatever you put into ViewState must be serializable, and I couldn't do that. So I stored the EditableLabels in a session-level dictionary where the key is a GUID saved in the ViewState.

The second problem, is that the `ControlFromPriviousPageLoad != ControlFromNextPageLoad`. New components get generate for each page load. Instead, I resort to comparing the IDs which are supposed to be unique for each page anyways.

I know that all of this sounds icky but ASP.NET is disgusting so lets just leave at that.

Resulting class: https://paste.rs/9bU.cs